# CodeIgniter Session Class handling session through database errors CI 2.0.2

Tags: codeigniter

I am storing data through CodeIgniter sessions, but for some reason, when I store session with large amount of data, it logs me out of my application.

In the user guide: "Note: Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the capacity. The encryption process in particular produces a longer data string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you are storing."

Does this mean, even if I have it store in database, I shouldn't store large data in my session?

Not to mention, it keeps adding 0.0.0.0 as IP and 0 as user agent...

```
'f2361497fefcd079523534c3230c3ac3', '0.0.0.0', '0', 1314307801, ''
```

Comment: make sure in your config you have it set to store the session information itself in the database, I believe it's `$config['sess_use_database']`, which needs to be set to true

Comment: I am storing a huge data in Session while using database, AFAIK shouldn't be a problem at your end too.

Comment: @Usman Do you mean you store CI sessions or PHP sessions?

Comment: @Usman are you using CI 2.0.3?

Comment: Nope, I have used 2.0.0 but I have not stored too much data while using this version. I have an old project where is used, 1.7.2 and I stored enough data there. Session class is not much changed since then, except a few new configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. What you can do to get around this is create an additional table in your database which has an id equal to your session_id, then you can make a query based on that.

Comment: Why does it work locally, not in production? localhost can hold larger amount of cookies?